# Load csv fails in GrapheneDB, "Couldn't load the external resource at:"

Tags: csv, neo4j, graphenedb

I try to import a CSV in GrapheneDB. But I have this error:

> Couldn't load the external resource at:/data/graph.csv

I have a local neo4j instance on my Mac and when I run my request, It's work. So the problem is not the path of the .csv.

I also tried to change the permissions of the file to 777 but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Juanjo from [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com).

When running LOAD CSV from Neo4j browser UI, bear in mind Neo4j won’t be able to access your filesystem. You should provide a publicly available URL instead, i.e. a file hosted on AWS S3.

For example:

`LOAD CSV FROM 'http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.3/csv/artists.csv' AS line`

Please take a look at other considerations for GrapheneDB users when importing data into Neo4j via CSV [here](http://www.graphenedb.com/blog/2015/01/13/importing-data-into-neo4j-via-csv/)